# Remove specified pattern from string in R

Tags: regex, r, text

I have a string like the following

```
s <- "abc a%bc 1.2% 234 1.2 (1.4%)) %3ed"
```

I would like to remove all "words" which have the %. So the result would be

```
"abc 234 1.2"
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: I do not know how to go about it

Comment: I would take a look at the `gsub` function to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
> gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", (gsub("\\s+", " " ,gsub("\\s+\\S*%\\S*(?=\\s+|$)", " ",input, perl=TRUE))))
#[1] "abc 234 1.2"
```

*Code Breakdown*

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", (gsub("\\s+", " " ,gsub("\\s+\\S*%\\S*(?=\\s+|$)", " ",input, perl=TRUE))))
                                           <--------------------------------------------------->
                                                     Remove strings with %
                        <------------------------------------------------------------------------>
                        Substitute extra spaces with single space from resultant string obtained from above
<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
      Trim initial and final whitespaces from the string obtained from above
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\\s+ #Match whitespaces
\\S* #Match all non whitespace character before % if its there
% #Match % literally
\\S* #Match all non whitespace character after % if its there
(?=\\s+|$) #Lookahead to check whether there is a space or end of string after matching word with %
```

Comment: Could explain the \\S*%\\S*(?=\\s+|$) part of your solution?

Comment: Thnx @rock321987 for the detailed solution

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
library(stringr)
s <- "abc a%bc 1.2% 234 1.2 (1.4%)) %3ed"
words<-unlist(str_split(s," "))
ind<-which(is.na(str_locate(unlist(str_split(s," ")),"%")[,1]))
vec<-words[ind]
res<-paste(vec, collapse = ' ')
res
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(s, "(?<=^|\\s)[^%\\s]+(?=\\s|$)")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "234" "1.2"
```

`(?<=^|\\s)` stands for looking behind either the beginning of the string or a white space;

`[^%\\s]+` matches a word that doesn't contain `%` and white space;

`(?=\\s|$)` stands for looking ahead of either the end of the string or a white space;

Comment: why are you including `()` and `|` inside character class?

Comment: @rock321987 Can you be a little bit more specific? I don't think I get what you mean.

Comment: `[]` is a character class..so it means that every character is treated literally..`[^(%|\\s)]` means match anything except `(`, `%`, `|`, `\s` or `)`

Comment: @rock321987 Get you. Thanks for pointing that out. Still a beginner on `regex`. :)

Comment: no problem..i have just written something about it **[here](https://rock321987.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/regex-tutorial-part-2/)** in Word of Caution section in 4.1 Character Class..just publicizing my blog..:
)

Answer (score 2):

How about this simple approach using base R:

```
s <- "abc a%bc 1.2% 234 1.2 (1.4%)) %3ed"
spl <- unlist(strsplit(s, " "))
spl[!grepl("%", spl)]

#[1] "abc" "234" "1.2"
```